# Capture process signal "Terminated" message output in shell pipeline

Tags: shell, process

When a process is ended by a signal, a message is output like `Terminated` or `Killed` depending on the signal used. Is it possible to capture that message ?

Take this example pipeline:

```
while true; do timeout 2 sleep 5; done
```

There is no output from it, however the `sleep` is terminated every 2 seconds. Add a `cat`:

```
while true; do timeout 2 sleep 5 | cat; done
```

It now outputs `Terminated` every 2 seconds but `cat` doesn't see it - if I replace `cat` with `tee somefile` then the file remaims empty.

I've tried redirecting `2>&1` in various places on the command-line but I cannot get the `Terminated` outputs into the file.

I think they're output by the `libc` linked into the terminal's shell rather than the commands in the loop.

Is it possible to get the `Terminated` and similar outout into the pipeline?

(Ultimately, I want to replace the `sleep` with a `curl` and the `cat` with an `awk` script and that processes both the `curl` output and the `Terminated` messages.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

Yes, it's the shell what prints `Terminated`. Upon `timeout 2 sleep 5 | cat` you see `Terminated` because `cat` gets terminated. And I *do* mean `cat`.

This is explained in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1261201/432690). `timeout` sends SIGTERM to its entire process group and in your case the group includes `sleep` *and* `cat`.

The process group includes `timeout` as well. It appears `timeout` is not killed by its own signal and this is the reason sole `timeout 2 sleep 5` does not make the shell print `Terminated`. But if you do `timeout -s KILL 2 sleep 5` then you will see `Killed` from the shell because SIGKILL can neither be caught nor ignored. When `timeout` kills `sleep` with SIGKILL, it also kills itself and the shell reacts.

So it's `cat` what matters for this `Terminated` you observed. Now if you replace `sleep` with `curl`, `cat` with `awk`, then `timeout` will terminate `curl` and `awk`. This doesn't matter though, because it's the shell what prints the message. If you really want to capture the message then you need `awk` in a pipe *after* the shell.

---

#### Solution

If you really want to capture the message then you need `awk` in a pipe after the shell that prints the message. And you need a "victim" process that gets terminated, without it there will be no message. And you need a shell that runs `timeout` in a process group with PGID equal to its PID, because this is crucial for the mechanism (see the linked answer). E.g. `awk` in this pipeline should successfully process the message:

```
bash -ic 'timeout 2 sleep 5 | cat' 2>&1 | awk '{print "This is the message: "$0}'
```

`-i` is important; without it `timeout` would not kill our poor condemned `cat`. Strictly it's not about interactive or non-interactive Bash. It's about job control being enabled (and it is enabled by default in interactive Bash) or disabled (by default in non-interactive). So this will also work:

```
bash -c 'set -m; timeout 2 sleep 5 | cat' 2>&1 | awk '{print "This is the message: "$0}'
```

---

#### More elegant solution

There's a simpler way to do what you want. If ultimately you want to run this in a script, then you can take advantage of the fact a shell interpreting a script should not create separate process groups for commands. In a non-interactive script `timeout … | awk` will not kill `awk`.

Now all you need is `timeout -v` that will tell you what it does. The following example is designed to be run as a non-interactive script. If you want to test it in an interactive Bash, you can, but you must disable job control first (`set +m`). This is the script:

```
#/bin/sh
timeout -v 2 sleep 5 2>&1 | awk '{print "This is the message: "$0}'
```

Replace `sleep` with `curl`. Your `awk` should look for `timeout: sending signal TERM to command '…'` instead of trying to detect `Terminated`.